# Webpack: Limit chunk files from dynamic imports

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, import, chunks

I'm doing dynamic imports of locale files for one of my npm-dependencies. My software is currently translated into 4 languages. The package however provides more than 50 different languages.

Since I'm doing the dynamic import like this

```js
import(/* webpackChunkName: "messages" */ `packagename/lib/locales/${locale}`).then(addMessages);
```

Webpack generates for every possible import a chunk file of course...

Now my question: Is there a way, similar to the `webpackChunkName`-Comment, to limit the module names Webpack needs to build chunks for?

My current solution is to copy the files I really need, to a separate folder in my project... This is of course far from ideal since I need to check for locale updates manually every time I update the package.

Thanks a lot in advance for your replies!